# Openlayers 4 Cluster polygons

Tags: openlayers, clustering

I have a layer with polygons in Openlayers 4 that I want to show as polygons when zoomed in and cluster them when I zoom out to a given level.

Ol.source.Cluster has a geometryFunction attribute where I translate the polygons into points which is necessary for the Cluster object (this seems reasonable to me, the distance between polygons are not intuitive)

The problem comes when I apply a Polygon Style to the layer, since the Cluster function transforms the polygons into points it doesn't show anything, is there a way to get around this using only one layer?

```js
var zoomedInStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'orange'
        })
    }),
    geometry: function(feature) {
        // Here I would need the original polygon
        return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
    }    
});

var zoomedOutStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'orange',
        width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1)'
    }),
    geometry: function(feature) {
        var type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
        if (type === 'Polygon')
            return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
    }
});

function featureStyleFunction(feature, resolution) {
    if (resolution > 0.5)
        return zoomedOutStyle;
    else
        return zoomedInStyle;
};

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJson)
});

function clusterFunction(feature) {
    return feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
};

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    source: source,
    geometryFunction: clusterFunction,
    distance: 20
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: clusterSource,
    style: featureStyleFunction
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution myself, the original features that make up the clustered feature are stored in a property called "features". My zoomed in style becomes:

```
var zoomedInStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'orange',
    width: 3
  }),
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1)'
  }),
  geometry: function(feature){
    var originalFeature = feature.get('features');
    return originalFeature[0].getGeometry();
  }
});
```

Comment: Apparently the geometry function is causing data loss while rendering.